Node.js : variables collision using net.createServer()
I am hosting a server with Node.js and using Net module to listen on TCP ports.
There are multiple clients devices sending data to the ports, data sent are formated and registered into the DB.
My problem : when one of my variables format (coming from another endpoint call) is null, it seems to have the value coming from another client call.
Here is the code
Main server.js code :
const Listener = require('./listeners/Listener');

Listener.launch(25152);

Listener.js code
const net = require('net');
const controller = require('../controllers/controller.js');
const geocoding = require('../controllers/geocoding.controller.js');

exports.launch = (PORTTCP) => {

    const serverTCP = net.createServer((socket) => {

        socket.on('data', (data) => {

            // Get the message type
            const messageType = data.toString('hex').substring(4,6);
            let addressPromise = null;

            switch (messageType) {

                case '13':
                    let positionMessage = controller.parsePositionMessage(data);
                    console.log("_______________________________________________________________")
                    console.log("positionMessage")
                    console.log(positionMessage)

                    addressPromise = geocoding.getAddress(positionMessage.Latitude, positionMessage.Longitude)
                    console.log("_______________________________________________________________")
                    console.log("addressPromise")
                    console.log(addressPromise)


                    addressPromise.then(address => {
                        console.log("_______________________________________________________________")
                        console.log("address")
                        console.log(address)
                        controller.savePosition(positionMessage, address == null ? address : null);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                    })

                    break;
            }
        });

        socket.on('end', () => {
            console.log('Connection ends');
        });

        socket.on('error', (err) => {
            console.error(`Error : ${err.message}`);
        });
    })

    serverTCP.listen(PORTTCP, () => {
        console.log(`Server listening TCP ${PORTTCP}`);
    });
}

Here is the code of geocoding.controller.js
const axios = require('axios');

const API_URL = 'https://api-url.com/?lon=';

exports.getAddress = (latitude, longitude) => {

    return axios.get(API_URL + longitude + '&lat=' + latitude);

}

The result of the third console.log "address" : when i restart server it's null when the geocoding is sending a null response (which is the wanted behavior).
BUT when the server has set the address variable at least once, then the next nulls results from the geocoding API will have the last resolved value (even if it's from another client call on the TCP port).
My guess : the variables are not reset for each new call on the TCP port, creating collisions for some behaviors.
Any way to solve this issue, maybe working on the Promises, or another way to create the Net server to avoid collisions between calls on the same port ?
Info :

I use Node.js v18.16.0

Thanks for help
